# Renaming with last save date

Tags: windows, powershell, rename

I have a problem with renaming files. My goal is renaming files with the last saving date. Unfortunately, by a wrong modification, the last modified dates are not the same as the last save date.

I tried to solve with this code in Powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.basename + " " + $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + $_.Extension}
```

It would be great if the code put the last save date in the end of the filename. But I cant modify it to be correct.

I can sort the files in the File Explorer by last save date. I need these dates to be put in the of the filename.

Anyone could help me solve this?

Comment: And by 'last save date' you mean creation date, so not the last modified date? Please show us what exactly happened when you did the modification (the code you used for that)

Comment: No, I mean last save date. Try to sort your files in File explorer (right click-sort-others-last save date.) I need that date. 

If I use the code, it works well, but with the last modification date, not with the last save date.

Comment: A FileInfo object has these date properties: 'CreationTime', 'CreationTimeUtc', 'LastAccessTime', 'LastAccessTime', 'LastWriteTime', 'LastWriteTimeUtc'. If you don't mean LastWriteTime, then my guess is you want the `CreationTime`.  You should be able to see what property you need by testing with `Get-Item -Path 'X:\WhereYourFilesAre' | Select-Object -First 1 -Property *Time*`

Comment: But how can file explorer see this detail? They are office files, docx and xlsx. If the file explorer sees that, I can use this data, or not?

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Have you tried what date property you want with the code line I gave you in my previous comment?

Comment: I tried. The result does not contain the last save date. On these files, the last save date does not equal the creation time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Get-Date` to convert the file's `LastWriteTime` to a string.

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.basename + " " + (Get-Date $_.LastWriteTime -Format "yyyy-MM-dd") + $_.Extension}
```

Comment: Why would you need `Get-Date` since the `LastWriteTime` property is already a DateTime object ???

Comment: To convert it from DateTime to a Sting in the right format `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: Yes, that is what `$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` does. Absolutely no need for `Get-Date`. Besides that, the OP wants a different date property, but up till now fails to explain what date that should be. The OP is talking about 'last save date' (which should be the LastWriteTime property).

Comment: It does not work. On these files, the last save date does not equal the creation , or the last write time